# Why does OverlappingFileLockException happen when locking a file?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I try to lock a file and write to it with the code below:

```
public class TrainSetBuildTask implements Runnable {
    private String pathname;
    public TrainSetBuildTask(String pathname){
        this.pathname = pathname;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
          try {
              String content = "content\n";
             //write to a file
             FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathname), true);
             FileChannel channel = os.getChannel();
             FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();
             if (lock != null) {
                ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(content.getBytes()); 
                channel.write(bytes);
                lock.release();
             }
             channel.close();
             os.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
 }
```

And new two thread with instances of the class:

```
    String pathname = "/home/sjtu123/test.arff";
    TrainSetBuildTask task1 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(task1);
    TrainSetBuildTask task2 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

Then I get the error OverlappingFileLockException. I wonder why this happens since I just lock the file once in each thread? How can fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot lock the same file more than once simultaneously.  Either you need to use java lock objects to ensure only one thread tries to lock the file at a time, or otherwise coordinate the threads to wait until no other thread is locking.

From the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29):

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.

Comment: Then what is usage of `FileLock` since it can not be used to coordinate the threads which wants to write file? @Attila

Comment: It is to prevent others (e.g. other programs) to access the file at the same time as the one that holds the lock.  The exception indicates that someone else (one of your own threads in this case) already has a lock on the file.  If you don't want to give up (from your program's perspective), you can try later, for example, in the hope that by that time the lock is released.

Comment: I have read the manual before I writing these code above and don't understand the meaning of them. Now I get it, thanks. @Attila

Answer (score 2):

Files are locked globally not just per-thread or per-process.

You need to run your two thread sequentially like this:

```
String pathname = "/home/sjtu123/test.arff";
TrainSetBuildTask task1 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
Thread t1 = new Thread(task1);
TrainSetBuildTask task2 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
Thread t2 = new Thread(task2);
t1.start();
t1.join(); // Wait for t1 to die.
t2.start();
```

New version after comments:

```
FileWriter pathname = new FileWriter("/home/sjtu123/test.arff");
TrainSetBuildTask task1 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
Thread t1 = new Thread(task1);
TrainSetBuildTask task2 = new TrainSetBuildTask(pathname);
Thread t2 = new Thread(task2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
t1.join();
j2.join();
synchronized (pathname){
    pathname.close();
}
```

and

```
public class TrainSetBuildTask implements Runnable {
    private FileWriter pathname;
    public TrainSetBuildTask(FileWriter pathname){
        this.pathname = pathname;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
          try {
             // Do work
             synchronized (pathname){
             // Write to file
             }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I hope t2 can do some jobs except for writing to the file. But your code means that thread t2 can begins to work only after that thread t1 has completed its work,no matter no matter whether t2 wants to write the file which is locked by t1. @Johannes

Comment: That was not entirely obvious from the question but take a look at the new version instead then. It might not be 100% correct but you should get the general idea.